# Why does PHP's DOMDocument remove leading whitespace from Processing Instruction nodes? (<?php ?>)

Tags: php, domdocument, libxml2

I am loading a XML-compliant PHP file into DOMDocument.

```
    $domDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $domDoc->recover            = TRUE;
    $domDoc->preserveWhiteSpace = TRUE;
    $domDoc->formatOutput       = FALSE;
    $domDoc->substituteEntities = FALSE;
    $domDoc->resolveExternals   = FALSE;
```

Despite preserving whitespace and instructing it to not format the output, I am still finding the leading whitespace in `<?php ?>` blocks removed when I save the XML with `$domDoc->saveXML()`.

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
<?php

// This is code.

// Something else.
    echo 'test';

?>
</html>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
<?php // This is code.

// Something else.
    echo 'test';

?>
</html>
```

I want the output to be as identical to the input as possible. Collapsing whitespace between attributes is acceptable, but collapsing whitespace between nodes or within a Processing Instruction is not okay. Why is PHP::DOMDocument() / libxml2 changing the contents of the PI? Will I need to resort to manual DOM echoing to keep the whitespace *completely* preserved?

Comment: Hi Jimp, from what I see its not the whitespace that's being removed but likely the new-line character. Its likely that you have 2 types of new-line in your file (eg: "\n" vs "\n\r"). Why don't you edit your file by removing all new lines and reapply them in a text editor and run the code again.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have already tried that and it made no difference. Paul's answer below is correct unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leading white space in a PI node *is* actually okay to collapse, as [the DOM considers the data portion of a processing instruction to be](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-1004215813):

> The content of this processing instruction. This is **from the first non white space character after the target** to the character immediately preceding the ?>.

(Emphasis mine.)

The `preserveWhiteSpace` setting only applies to text nodes, which is why that doesn't help you here.

In any case I would advise not relying on embedded PHP to be treated as a processing instruction as PHP can contain `?>` within it (e.g. as part of a string literal) which would terminate the processing instruction early.

Comment: So the spec requires it... How odd that the XML spec would specify a whitespace preference where it is providing a control mechanism, as if the instruction processor couldn't handle that extra whitespace. The problem for me is a coder using my UI will want their code back untouched, and I cannot distinguish between inline PHP and a massive block of code that the author starts on a new line. I have been looking through the libxml2 source and have found no option to relax that behavior. I guess pre and post substitution is my only option.

Comment: Also, I just tried echoing the PI's `nodeValue`, `textContent`, and `data` properties, and all three removed the leading whitespace. I was hoping at least `textContent` would have the unaltered version, but it appears libxml2 is using the SAX parser with instruction to completely ignore it (like the spec describes).

Comment: Oh, and thank you for the recommendation about not embedding PHP in XML. I've encountered exactly what you describe, but since this document is actually a part of a much larger XML document structure, I've had to apply a few rules to ensure the PHP is always XML compliant. I'll probably begin storing the PHP PI as <php> nodes with escaped CDATA text so I can remove this restriction.